# Implementing two TCP congestion control algorithms

Tags: omnet++, inet

Firstly, my apologies should this not be the correct forum for this question. I am trying to implement two tcp congestion control algorithms in OMNeT/INET for my thesis.

The first one is TCP-FIT, for which I have found pseudocode at http://www.tcpengines.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/tcp-whitepaper.pdf.
The other one is TCP-Illinois, of which I have found a linux implementation at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_illinois.c.

I cannot understand how to implement a few variables and methods in both mechanisms, and I would appreciate your help in figuring them out. A bit of help with the variable types would be welcome, as well.

In brief, for TCP-FIT:

- *epoch_start* and *update_epoch* (I understand that epoch can be synonymous with RTT)
- *alpha* (value)
- *n* - what is it?
- Is the RTT_cnt calculation correct ( under receivedDataAck() )?
- Is the tcpFitUpdateN() function correct?
- Have I implemented the pseudocode right?

For TCP-Illinois:

- *snd_cwnd_cnt* -- I think this is just a counter of how many packets have been ACKED.
- *snd_cwnd_clamp* -- Top limit of congestion window, I think I have it right.
- *end_seq* -- it seems to be needed, but I do not understand the "ack" parameter in *if (after(ack, ca->end_seq)) {...}*, which comes from the function *tcp_illinois_cong_avoid(struct sock *sk, u32 ack, u32 acked) {...}*
- *tp->snd_nxt* -- is it equivalent to OMNeT++ state->snd_nxt?
- *sum_rtt* and *max_rtt* -- Do I calculate these values right?

To my understanding, after reading the paper provided in the linux implementation, TCP-Illinois is functioning in the same manner as TCP-NewReno except the AIMD part. I bet this means I can keep most of the code of TCP-NewReno intact, except the TCP-SACK part and AIMD.

I would also appreciate any hints on the implementation and, of course, any comments on the correctness of the code. My current and almost complete implementation can be found on github, at https://github.com/SpyrosMArtel/TCP-Fit-Illinois.

Should you need more details or clarifications, feel free to bother me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: dear G.Rog your post looks more like a thread which requires discussion, rather than a SO question dealing with a concrete problem. Only someone who knows the protocols really well can get answer your questions. If you don't have well defined problem which needs an answer I am afraid your post will be flagged as `mainly opinion based`

Comment: have you run any simulation? does the protocol behave as you expect? have you collected results? are they as expected?